# how to start creating game 2D for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm `iOS` development and I want to create one simple game for `iOS` and I don't know that how to start ?
please tell and guide me about it (for example guide me related sources books or tutorials movie)

I want to start creating simple game.... please help.

Comment: or `SpriteKit` or simply `2d game ios` and then delete this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you tutorial on http://www.raywenderlich.com , for example [How To Make A Simple iPhone Game with Cocos2D 2.X Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25736/) is good start. Using cocos2d-x will provide easy android porting.